# Gitlab Client in Login Redirect Loop

Tags: macos, nginx, configuration, gitlab

I have been doing some work trying to update our gitlab servers. Somewhere along the line, something in the configuration changed and now I can't access the web client. The backend starts up correctly and when I run **rake gitlab:check** everything comes back as green. Same for nginx, as far as I can tell it is working correctly. When I try to go to the landing page in the browser though, I keep getting an error about 'too many redirects'.

Looking at the browser console, I can see that it is repeatedly trying to redirect to the login page until the browser gives up and throws an error. I did some looking around, and most of the answers seem to involve going to the login page directly and then changing the landing page from the admin settings. When I tried that I got the same problem. Apparently any page on my domain wants to redirect to the login, leaving me with an infinite loop.

I'm also seeing some potentially related errors in the nginx logs. When I try to hit the sign in page the error log is showing

> open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.15.9/html/users/sign_in" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Is that even the correct directory for the gitlab html views? If not how do I change it?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**Environment:**

OSX 10.11.6 El Capitan

Gitlab 8.11

nginx 1.15.9

My config files. I have removed some commented out lines to save on space.

**nginx.config**

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include servers/*;
}
```

**nginx/servers/gitlab**

```
upstream gitlab-workhorse {

server unix:/Users/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab-workhorse.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

  listen 0.0.0.0:8081;
  listen [::]:8081;
  server_name git.my.server.com; ## Replace this with something like gitlab.example.com
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice

  ## See app/controllers/application_controller.rb for headers set

  ## Individual nginx logs for this GitLab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 0;
    gzip off;

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab-workhorse;
  }

}
```

Comment: Post your gitlab config as well see what nginx config has been generated, post that config too. May be some paths have got messed up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer after several days of digging. At some point my default config file (/etc/default/gitlab) got changed. For whatever reason, my text editor decided to split gitlab_workhorse_options into two lines. As a result, gitlab was missing the arguments for authSocket and document root and was just using the default values. If that wasn't bad enough, the line split started on a $ character, so it looked like nano was just doing a word wrap.